# How do I see what blueprint was discovered for the notification "New Blueprint Discovered"?

Tags: starbound

I recently landed on a Desert biome in the Beta sector and as I was starting to dig into some loose sand I was picking up some loose items and I saw a notification with the others:

> New Blueprint Discovered

Is there a way to tell which blueprint this was, or is there a list of locations/actions that result in discovering new blueprints (like discovering Snow Infantry Armor on Snow planets)?  Can I have just "loosened" a blueprint in the planet?

Comment: You probably got "sandstone block" as the new item you can build. You get those by digging up sandstone for the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search function for crafting includes the materials and descriptions, so if you note what material you acquired to earn the notification, you can search for it at the crafting tables to see what sort of results appear.

Comment: This is the best way to find out at the moment unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Currently, if you aren't informed of what the blue print is when you first acquire it (such as "new blueprint: mushroom hat"), then the only way to know is to look through your inventory (for an actual "blueprint"), or to look through all your crafting options carefully.

Answer (score 1):

New blueprints will now be marked with a blue "NEW" label, so you'll see it as you scroll down your crafting lists. But if you missed the name in your notifications entirely, you might have more than one new blueprint available. The label is only removed when you select the blueprint though, so if you don't make a habit of regularly scrolling down your crafting lists and selecting every new blueprint there is, this feature will be a bit less useful than it might have been otherwise.